# PHP : integrating static HTML content with resolved PHP variables?

Tags: php, templates

I am working in a project which has the following restriction defined:
My PHP files must not have more than one opening or closing tag.
So it's PHP from top to bottom, but I am allowed to add static content by the means of 'import'.

What are proper/elegant ways to add static HTML content to my PHP index file (like outputting a website menu header or a formular) and at the same time resolve PHP variables inside the file.

Like a formular which makes a HTTP POST (login or register) and displays the previously entered email address in case of a mismatch, etc etc.

One way would be

```
echo "<form ...> \n <input ... value='$lastemail'>";
```

But I dislike the quoting. echo <<< EOF is also not great for the purpose imho.
I think HTML code should stay together without separating it into multiple echos so it can be validated.

So I am looking for a good solution to import/integrate static HTML code, like a template system and still resolve PHP variables.

Update:
The restriction is made to not mix HTML and PHP code.

I think I will need an engine/class/function which replaces variables inside a HTML template with PHP code. Like searching for ${variable} and replacing it with the php $variable as if it was PHP code.
I just thought maybe there is already something existing within PHP to solve that.

Update:
Should I oppose the requirement ?
Would be very interesting to hear the oppinion of a professional PHP developer with long history in that area. (On The restriction is made to not mix HTML and PHP code.  )

Comment: so just keep html and php in separate files, I don't see what's the problem

Comment: @php_nub_qq: I think I explained the problem quite good ?
Did you really read through ?

Comment: Yes, I have read your question and I still don't understand what the problem is. Almost every MVC framework does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a templating system? There are plenty out there for PHP. Some nice ones are (in my opinion):

1. [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), which is very small and fast
2. [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), a little larger, but also fast and very popular

Comment: I think that is going in the direciton I need, I will look into them.
As I have to audit any library or framework, I will need something well working, small code and high performance.

Never heard of Twig or Smarty before!

Comment: I understand, you have some homework to do : ) I've used both of these template engines and have found them to work very well, but have a slight preference towards Twig, which I think has a more elegant syntax. Of course there are lots of other template/replacement engines to choose from, which you'll find via Google, but I couldn't comment on anything else. Good luck in finding something that suits your needs!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I provide now may seem lengthy and strenuous to enact but would one of the best ways to solve problems with such constraints. Create a database with two tables, one of which would store all the static data i.e. HTML code whereas the other would store dynamic data i.e. data that you want to be personalised. You can then use the database to separately eject dynamic and static data, all using just pure PHP.

```
<?php
  $host = "127.0.0.1";
  $user = "root";
  $password = "****";
  $db = "project";
  $txt = NULL;
  $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);
  if(!conn){
     header("location:error.htm");
  }
  $query1 = "SELECT dynamicdata FROM projectdynamicdata WHERE pagename ='index'";
  $resultset1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset1){
      $txt = $row["dynamicdata"];
  }
  $query2 = "SELECT htmlpage FROM projectstaticdata WHERE pagename='index'";
  $resultset2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset){
      echo $row["htmlpage"];
  }
  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This is what I would to solve such a problem.

Comment: I should have specified it better (will update my question)
The php start and end tags have to be at first and last line of the page.

The restriction is made to not mix HTML and PHP code within one file.